# Excel - two graphs in one (side by side)

Tags: excel, plot, charts, merge, ms-office

I have two graphs in Excel, but I want to merge the charts into one graph. As you can see, I have reduced the size of the chart in `graph1` and I want to move the chart in the `graph2` into the empty space in `graph1`

[image]

Comment: It will probably be easier to keep the graphics as two separate charts. Shrink them both without all the white space, and keep them closer together. Same effect: http://imgur.com/X1kLEij

Answer (score 2):

I think there are many ways to do this in basic excel like jrichall showed you but If you are willing to use an excel add-in to create this double chart, you could try FunFun.

It allow you to code javascript in excel, merging two charts in one is pretty easy in programming languages such as javascript.

Here is a working code I have written for you:

https://www.funfun.io/1/#/edit/5a3d0933b848f771fbcdec96

As you can see, I use a Json file to acquire the data used in the spreadsheet. Once the data is "stored", I can use it with javascript and create my charts.

I use Chart.js library to create those two charts, I basically copied this code twice to get two chart (I just changed the data and the word `"bar"` by `"line"`):

```
var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      // x axis represented by labels
      labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        datasets: dataset
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
      display: false
    },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              min: 0,
              max: 10
            }
        }
        ]
      }
    },
    animation: false
});
```

The documentation of [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) is pretty good and has a lot of examples for different type of charts.

Once you are satisfied with your chart, you can load it in excel by pasting the URL in the [Funfun add-in](https://www.funfun.io/1/msaddin). Here is how it looks like:

[image: final]

I used a css file to correctly align the title (`.label`).

**Disclosure : I’m a developer of funfun**

Answer (score 0):

I think a little more info would help. How is your data set up? Are you using pivot tables / pivot charts? I think I can help once I get a better idea of where your data is coming from and how you have it set up.

Edit to add example of how I work with charts:
[Multi-graph chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIW5L.png)

Second Edit: 
[Multi Chart 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnGJ7.png)

Comment: The chart above is a simple example about what I want. I just want to combine two charts into one graph in Excel, as simple as that.I dont want to make it more complex. It can relate to `par(mfrow = c(1, 2))` in R where you combine two graphs together.

Comment: Oh ok. I typically work with charts with multiple series, so I can't really help with R. I edited my response above with an example of what I would have done (finished chart). If you're using par() in R, you probably already know how to create charts outside of VBA. I'm happy to explain my process, but I don't think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: I do not ned help with R, my problem is to do the same in Excel. To make two charts in one graph and have them side-by-side.

Comment: I added another example to my answer above ("Multi Chart 2"). It uses some formatting, but if you're looking for something simple it might work. I basically created my two charts, put them side by side, removed the chart borders, removed the grid lines, and then created a border around the whole thing. You could mess with the formatting to make it nicer looking. Based on this [image from Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/images/layout1.jpg), you could create a very similar look in excel using this method. If you think this could work, I can explain the steps further.

Comment: Is it possible for you to click on the graph and save it as PDF (the whole graph) ?

Comment: It is possible to export it to a PDF, but not by just clicking on the graph. If you select the cells that surround the graph (so, where ever you set your border if you choose to), you can either click on File > Save As > PDF or XPS > Options > Selection (Excel 2007) or File > Export > PDF or XPS > Options > Selection (Excel 2010)

Comment: I also just tested copy/paste, using the same method of selecting the cells where the charts sit, into Word (if you wanted to add more information / instructions) and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed something above, I think that we can make this a bit simpler by editing your chart as follows:

- Select `Chart Tools` in the ribbon
- Select 'Change Chart Type` icon
- Select `Combo` (last option)
- Change one of the axes to be a Secondary axis and change type to Line instead of Bar.

[image: Edit Chart Type]

[image: Combined result]